Creating a proportional stacked bar plot in python
I am attempting to create a proportional stacked bar plot with (6) categories that add up to 100. I have a dataframe with several values for each month of the year (n = 12) in each of the six categories (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6).
I tried using matplotlib m.patches to assemble mean values for each bar and came up with the graph below. I want to stack each of the bars on top of each other. Currently, they are laid on top of one another.
Are there any simple additions/revisions that allow me to stack the bars?
Code and attempted bar plot:
# import libraries
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

df = pd.read_csv('marsh fig 7.csv')
plt.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] = 12
plt.figure(figsize=(600/my_dpi, 300/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)

bar1 = sns.barplot(x="Month",  y="Percent_C1", data=df,     color='darkgreen')
bar2 = sns.barplot(x="Month",  y="Percent_C2", data=df,     color='mediumseagreen')
bar3 = sns.barplot(x="Month",  y="Percent_C3", data=df,     color='goldenrod')
bar4 = sns.barplot(x="Month",  y="Percent_C4", data=df,     color='sienna')
bar5 = sns.barplot(x="Month",  y="Percent_C5", data=df,     color='steelblue')
bar6 = sns.barplot(x="Month",  y="Component Proportion",     data=df, color='darkblue')

# add legend
bar1 = mpatches.Patch(color='darkgreen', label='% C1')
bar2 = mpatches.Patch(color='mediumseagreen', label='% C2')
bar3 = mpatches.Patch(color='goldenrod', label='% C3')
bar4 = mpatches.Patch(color='sienna', label='% C4')
bar5 = mpatches.Patch(color='steelblue', label='% C5')
bar6 = mpatches.Patch(color='darkblue', label='% C6')
plt.ylim(0,40)
plt.text(0, 39, "Marsh", ha='left', va='top',fontsize=12,     fontweight='normal', color="black")

ax2 = plt.twinx()
df2 = pd.read_csv('SRS1 Water Level.csv')
ax = sns.pointplot(x="Month", y="Water Depth (cm)", data=df2,         color="black", linestyles=':', label=None, errwidth=1,     capsize=0.2)   

plt.legend(handles=[bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4, bar5, bar6])
plt.show()


Not sure about @JohanC's comment, because seaborn can stack bars, also see this approach. I would just compute whatever quantities you need (eg to normalize totals), if that's the issue.

Could you please explain the difference between "I want to stack each of the bars on top of each other." and "Currently, they are laid on top of one another." — I'm asking because I cannot semantically distinguish the two situations… Maybe you could post the graph produced by your code and a sketch of the different, desired outcome.


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib.colors import rgb_to_hsv
np.random.seed(20240801)

Months = 'Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec'.split()
n_months = 12
values = np.random.randint(3, 9, (12, 6)) # montly categorical values
colors = 'darkgreen mediumseagreen goldenrod sienna steelblue darkblue'.split()

# data = ... is a string, equivalent to data = open('….csv').read()
data = '\n'.join(['Month C1 C2 C3 V4 C5 C6']+[mon+' '+' '.join(str(v) for v in val)
                                              for mon, val in zip(Months, values)])

# split the headers line from montly categorical values,
# separate "x" label from rest
headers, *values = [line.strip().split() for line in data.split('\n') if line]
months, *categories = headers

# values are  by month, transpose them and build a "dataframe" 
df = dict(zip(headers, zip(*values)))
for category in categories
    df[category] = np.array(df[category]).astype(float)

###  HERE STARTS THE interesting CODE #################################
# needed for normalized stacked bars                                 ##
bottom = np.zeros(n_months)                                          ##
totals_by_month = np.array([sum(df[category][n]                      ##
                            for category in categories)              ##
                            for n in range(n_months)])               ##
#######################################################################
# PLOTTING
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4), layout='constrained')
fig.set_facecolor('#e0f0ff') # cosmetic

# in reverse so we go from bottom (C6) to top (C1)                   ## 
for category in categories[::-1]:                                    ##
    values = 100*df[category]/totals_by_month                        ##
    bars = ax.bar(df[months], values, label=category, bottom=bottom, ##
                   ec='grey', lw=0.5, color=colors.pop())            ##
    color_is_dark = rgb_to_hsv(bars[0]._facecolor[:-1])[-1]<0.65     ##
    for bar in bars:                                                 ##
        h, w, x, y = bar._height, bar._width, bar._x0, bar._y0       ##
        ax.text(x+w/2, y+h/2-0.2, str(round(h))+'%',                 ##
                ha='center', va='center', fontsize=8, weight='bold', ##
                color='white' if color_is_dark else 'black')         ##
    bottom += values                                                 ##                    

plt.title("Category percentages month by month")
# fix the legend reversing the legend elements, to have C1 at the top
h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.legend(h[::-1], l[::-1], loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
# cosmetic, I prefer a little gap beneath the bars
ax.set_ylim(bottom=-2)
ax.axhline(0, ls='-', color='lightgrey')

# That's All, Folks
plt.show()

For reference
Month C1 C2 C3 V4 C5 C6
Jan 8 3 7 8 4 6
Feb 6 5 6 6 7 6
Mar 4 6 3 3 7 7
Apr 6 3 6 3 4 6
May 4 7 3 7 4 4
Jun 7 3 3 3 4 3
Jul 4 3 4 7 3 8
Aug 7 4 7 3 8 6
Sep 5 8 3 4 3 5
Oct 4 4 8 8 4 4
Nov 3 7 3 6 5 7
Dec 6 6 4 7 3 7

